# How to create a clickable "tag cloud" to populate a subform?

Tags: ms-access, user-interface, hyperlink, relational-database, subform

I've been lurking around for years reading up on all sorts of topics.  Professionally I'm a Systems Interface Specialist/Interface Architect. I can work wonders with tcl, Cloverleaf, HL7, even Excel, but Microsoft Access eludes me. It repeatedly befuddles and confounds me.  Everything that would seem simple and logical to me is neither of those things where MS Access is concerned.

So, I've come to you.  Honestly, I'm not even sure I'll be able to put into the correct "technical" words what I want to do.  I only know how I want things to appear to function when I'm finished.

I have built a very "simple" relational database to be used by authors who collect sentences or sentence snippets for use/inspiration in writing.  There are three tables:

- **tblPhrases** contains an autonumber field *idxPhrases* and a memo field *Phrase*.
- **tblTags** contains an autonumber field *idxTags* and a memo field *Tag*.
- **tblTagsToPhrases** contains an autonumber field *idxTagsToPhrases* and two number fields: *Tags_index* and *Phrases_index*

The first two tables require that all fields be unique.

Clearly (or not so?), the third table is the many-to-many connection.  It allows for there to be many tags associated with a phrase and more than one phrase to be associated with any one tag.

I have figured out how to set up a form and subform but it looks clunky as you can see and it's not at all what I had imagined.
[image: Screenshot]

What I really want instead of the dropdown combo box in the keyword/tag subform -- which does populate from tblTags and when I select something, correctly populates tblTagsToPhrases and when I return to that Phrase in the form, displays the list of associated tags...

What I would really like instead is to have the values in tblTags appear in a "Tag Cloud" like on a webpage.  Then I can click on the hypertext control for that value and it will populate a text field, adding commas between the selections.  However, behind the scenes, it's really just adding to tblTagsToPhrases.  I should also be able to type in a new Tag right there.  Basically, treating the field like a Tag field on a bookmarking site.

And if I were really honest, I'd like to be able to display the phrases as hypertext too because that would look much less clunky and less like a database.

Can anyone give some direction to get from where I am to there.

Thanks so much in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

You need VBA to do this, using the Timer event of the form to move labels around randomly, using some detailed maths to get them to move in a direction-of-flow, rather than completely random. Each label (or textbox) would first have to be populated with the field-values. If you only want a static tag-cloud then you wouldn't need the the Timer event.

If you don't know VBA then you'll have to search but I think it unlikely that you will find an example of this (and if you do, will you be able to adapt it?). In fact, if you get this to work, and include the animation, I would expect it to exhibit noticeable flicker.

I think you should ask yourself if you intend to build a database or a web-application. (If you are struggling with Access, why go even further and attempt to make it do things that it wasn't designed for?)

Comment: Well, I am open to recommendations on another method of displaying the already entered "tags".  I do not have an issue with typing to enter into a field -- I usually type faster than most auto-fill. ;) 

My issue has been memory related as in I cannot remember all the "tags" I previously entered, which is why I want to see them so I don't create semi-duplicates.

And, yes, I do think having 1 to 6 of those dropdown controls in the subform is ugly. :P